# Filter and group by user age - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a chart table which i would like to group and count by integer range (ages) of the users in that object.

Table for example:

```
Name   Age
John   21
Steve  24
Dan    29 
Mike   31
```

and my expected result is:

```
[20-25] [26-31]
   2       2
```

I was playing around with the annotate function of Django but couldn't figure it out so far.
Any suggestions aboout this?

My views.py:

```
qs = Post.objects.filter(spot=spot).annotate(
     age_group = Case(
          When(attendant__profile__age__range=[21, 27], then=Value('21-27')).count(),
          When(attendant__profile__age__range=[29, 33], then=Value('29-33')).count(),
          default=Value('No group'),
          output_field=CharField(),
             )
        ).values('age', 'age_group')
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)

    def age(self):
        return int((datetime.date.today() - self.birthday).days / 365.25)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Conditional Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation) to count only rows that fit a certain criteria. You cannot filter on a value provided by an instance's method, but you have to do the calculation inside the database using Django's ORM.

See the example below for annotating one age group, probably calculating the age exactly is a bit more complicated (look into Django's Field Lookups if you eg. only want to use the [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#date)), but you should get the idea.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.db.models import Count, Q

now = datetime.now()
year = timedelta(days=1) * 365

qs = Post.objects.filter(spot=spot).annotate(
    age_group_1=Count("pk", 
        filter=Q(attendant__profile__birthday__range=[now - (27 * year), now - (21 * year)])
    )
)
for post in qs:
    print(post, post.age_group_1)
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is totally different to my question… I need to group the users attendant in an specific Post by age…

Comment: Ah sorry misread the question somehow, but I edited the example code so that it should also work with annotating the Post objects..

Comment: Mmm we are in the way I guess... This is actually returning me the queryset: <QuerySet [<Post: Post object (32)>, <Post: Post object (33)>, <Post: Post object (34)>, <Post: Post object (35)>, <Post: Post object (36)>]>

Comment: And for what im checking, it's not taking in consideration the birthday age also ='(

Comment: You can iterate over the queryset and access the `age_group_1` attribute, or use `values()` on it... Or what do you mean with "it"s not taking in cosideration the birthday age"?